# Is this particular function not well defined?

Tags: functions, definition

I was looking more into what it means for a function to be well defined, and I believe I understand it. Suppose we have a function $f:A \rightarrow B$ where $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and 
$B = \{1,2,3\}$ given by $f(1) = 1, f(2) = 2, f(3) = 3$.

However given the construction of f, f is not well defined since everything in A must be mapped onto something in B, and 4 is not mapped to anything?

Comment: $f$ is just a relation from $A$ to $B$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not use the term *not well-defined* to describe this case of incomplete definition, where some element is not mapped to anything. *Not well-defined* typically refers to having a complete definition that may be ambiguous in some way, and then one shows that there is no ambiguity to show that it is well-defined. For example, if I map an equivalence class $[x]$ to $f(x)$ under some map $g$, I would need to show that this map is independent of the choice of representative of equivalence class used, that is, if $[x]=[y]$ then $f(x)=f(y)$, so that $g$ is well-defined.

Comment: I agree (for the same reason), and would say that $f$ is instead *not a function*.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I suspected saying f is not "well defined" was not the best, but rather f is simply not a function.

Comment: I think as a matter of usage you may be mistaken.  Wouldn't it be usual to say that the function $x\to x^{1/2}$ is not well-defined for negative $x$?

Comment: @MJD but since you called it a function you must have meant the principal branch, in which case it _is_ well-defined.

Comment: I'm talking about the function on $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$.